# Failed to Attach to Script process in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, debugging, asp-classic, w3wp

I am trying to attach to w3wp.exe to debug classic asp.

i am attaching to type "Script", but get the following error:

Failed to attach to these type(s) of code: Script: A debugger is already attached.

i saw online that maybe another program is running on the background and is using "Script".

how can i find out what program uses it? and possibly kill it? or is there another way to go around it.

maybe i can debug classic asp without attaching to Script? this is the only way i've been able to do it in the past.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you have to configure asp in your iis and set server-side debugging to true.

then you can use the "stop" keyword in your asp script in the line you want to set a "break Point". when the line is executed a window will popup and you can start visual Studio to debug your asp script.